# Does NSUndoManager retain objects?

Tags: nsundomanager

I do the following:

```
    Path2D *pathToRemove = [path copy];
    [[[self undoManager] prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] removePath:pathToRemove atIndex:index];
[pathToRemove autorelease];
```

I also have a clear button that does:

```
[undoManager removeAllActions];
```

Problem is that the removeAllActions crashes the app. When I removed the [pathToRemove autorelease], it worked (or at least didn't crash. It could still be a memory leak). I guess I was assuming that the undoManager retained 'pathToRemove' when passed in the 'prepareWithInvocationTarget' call.

Is that not the case? If that is not the case then the crash could happen because the call to 'removeAllActions' is releasing the 'PathToRemove' object. But that would mean it is a bug in NSUndoManager which is highly unlikely.

I can say that my copyWithZone implementation is not likely to be the culprit either since NSLog outputs for '[pathToRemove description]' and '[path description]' show different addresses as expected.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ok I figured it out. 'prepareWithInvokationTarget' DOES retain its arguments. My problem was that my copyWithZone method was indeed incorrect. I had an object that was not being copied and only retained. Thus when 'RemoveAllActions' released the objects and they went into their respective Dealloc methods, the release of this member variable that wasn't "copied" created a double release scenario thus causing the crash. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the `prepareWithInvocationTarget:` method doesn't retain the arguments passed to it. From the [`NSUndoManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/RegisteringUndo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000206) documentation, it appears that it simply captures the [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation) and later replays it. `NSInvocation`objects don't retain the objects in their arguments unless specifically asked to do so.

That doesn't quite explain the crash, because `removeAllActions` is just supposed to clear the undo stack and not do anything to the objects.

Hope this helps some in tracking down the source of the crash.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try using: registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object. According to the doc this retains the object so I should be able to release it after calling this registration method.

Comment: That's not correct, prepareWithInvocationTarget *does* retain all its arguments but does *not* retain its target.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's not a release/retain issue. You've to clear the stack after the Undo/Redo Operation. To do this you can register your viewController for the NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(clearUndoRedoStack) name:NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and then clear the stack onto the specified method:

```
- (void)clearUndoRedoStack {
    [undoManager removeAllActions];
}
```